# Can't Allocate More RAM to Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've checked all the other answers and I can't seem to find one that fits my situation.
I'll go ahead and list everything I've tried, that way we can cruise through the generic answers.

**Heads Up:** New PC. Downloaded Java 64x. Copy and Pasted old PC's .minecraft folder. Same specs except for CPU and GPU. It is Modded.

**Problem:** Everytime I launch Minecraft without allocating any RAM it starts fine but with only 500MB of RAM allocated. I can't add arguments or I get a "Java Virtual Machine" Error. Changing the Environment Variables doesn't affect the 500MB of allocated RAM. If I just add the -Xmx1G etc... argument it launches with 500MB of RAM regardless, unless I add more than 4GB then it spits out the "Java Virtual Machine" error.

**Things I've Tried**

- Installed Java 64x
- Reinstalled Java 64x
- Re-reinstalled Java 64x
- Ensured I was using 64x Java and not 32x
- Made changes to Environment Variables
- Turned it off and back on again
- Set specific arguments
- Reinstalled Minecraft.
- Re-reinstalled Minecraft.
- Forced Minecraft to Update (with an error)
- Googled fixes for several hours
- Found nothing
- Posted here and several other places.
- Awaiting replies...

*Also, don't know if this is important, but the Java website can't verify my Java.

Comment: Could you give some specifics about the Java version you're trying to use, as well as the Minecraft version, your Windows version and the command you're trying to use to start Minecraft?

Comment: Also be good to know how much available RAM you have...

Comment: also, how much minecraft starts with isn't important, it requests RAM up to the limit its been allocated. If you want it to start with more, use Xms<ram>.

Comment: This is a issue on many devices (including mine) for Minecraft. Even though Minecraft is a game that can perform pretty well, it isn't _perfectly_ programmed. Minecraft sometimes uses only one core of the processor, meaning there is a limited amount of data that can be allocated in your RAM at once.
As far as I know, there is no way to completely fix this issue. The only way would be to change the game itself, which would require different scripts, game engine, etc. Unfortunately, re-making the whole game isn't probably going to happen anytime soon just because of this issue.

Comment: Do you mean "64 bit"? Because I doubt you really installed Java 64 times. Also, what's the error you get?

Comment: I honestly don't know what was causing it but it managed to fix itself after the third attempt at restarting and relaunching minecraft.

Comment: Just to add - You can add as much RAM as you want to Java. If you put a number greater than what you have, it'll either fallback to a default value or outright crash because you don't have enough memory available (depends on which release you have).

Answer (score 1):

`-Xmx` is for the maximum heap space. It doesn't tell Java this is what should be started with, but is the maximum. `-Xms` is for the minimum, so what the JVM starts with. But really, what it starts with is a much smaller concern than the maximum.

That being said, if you observe that the issue comes when you go beyond 4GB RAM, that is a clear indicator that what you have is a 32-bit program. Whatever you did to ensure you use 64-bit Java can't have been right.

Answer (score 0):

To those having similar issues in the future:

Typing `cat /proc/meminfo` into the command line will inform you how much RAM you have free on your computer. Oftentimes there's just a lack of memory, meaning you need to either close some programs or upgrade your RAM.

If you definitely have enough memory (at least 1GB more than you want to dedicate), then adding `-d64` to the same place where you put `-Xmx` and `-Xms` will force Minecraft to use Java x64 rather than any Java x86 that somehow snuck onto your machine.

Furthermore, you can try adding the 64-bit java to your computer's PATH:

1. Right click on My Computer/Computer (on win10 simply enter settings and search "system settings" then skip to step 4)
2. Go to Properties
3. Go to Advanced system settings (or just Advanced)
4. Click Environment variables in the bottom right.
5. Add the location of the folder that `javaw.exe` is in to the PATH by clicking `Path` then clicking "Edit", then clicking "New" and adding it there - ensure there is a semicolon (`;`) at the end, or it won't work. (Note: If the `PATH` variable doesn't exist among "User variables" click "New", and set the following: Variable name = `PATH`, Variable value = location of the folder `javaw.exe` is in (this is often Program Files).)

If the issue persists beyond that, you don't have 64-bit Java installed.